# Pagination within result view

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, pear

I am currently using PHP PEAR for simple pagination.  Does anyone have a recommended method or example of how to page record-sets within an existing result view?  The typical model would be something like this:

```
Search -> Results -> View Record
```

With paging only possible in the Results page...  What I am asking about is the ability to page within the "View Record" as well. So you would have the ability to easily page to the next (or previous) record in the result set while you are viewing a record.  Obviously I could pass the record-set state and pagination variables from the results page to the view page, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do this.  Any idea or recommendations?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the PEAR Pagination code will help you here.

Assuming your View Record page has a query string parameter RecordID, you could create `Prev` and `Next` links on your View Record page. In order to get the previous and next records, you could use SQL statements like this:

**PREV** - `SELECT RecordID FROM records WHERE RecordID < '" . $CurrRecordID . "' ORDER BY RecordID DESC LIMIT 1`

**NEXT** - `SELECT RecordID FROM records WHERE RecordID > '" . $CurrRecordID . "' ORDER BY RecordID ASC LIMIT 1`

If your Results page sorts differently, change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it using PEAR pagination.  To test this I duplicated the search results page, expanded the record-set, and pulled all the detail information in from the View Record page.  Basically I had my duplicate results page display the View Records details instead of the search result fields.  Next I restricted the pagination results down to 1 record per page.  To link it back to the original search results page I passed the pageID number to the duplicate page.  I had to offset it by calculating what page the result set was on.  That way the pageID would accurately reflect the number of the result.  If i was returning 20 records per page and I was on page 2 of the result set... I knew that the first record in the result needed a pageID of 21.